# Initializing map with greater comparator

Tags: c++

I am confused as to why initializing map with std::less comparator works but std::greater does not.

The constructor I believe I am using is this one

```
explicit map( const Compare& comp,
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

Code example:

```cpp
typedef std::map<double, std::queue<something>> mydef;
auto t1 = mydef{std::less<double>()} // works
auto t2 = mydef{std::greater<double>()} // does not ( error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'mydef' .... )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your need to take the definitions of `Compare` into account. It is taken from the `map`'s template arguments:

```cpp
template<
    class Key,
    class T,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>, // <-- here
    class Allocator = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>
> class map;
```

Thus making the constructor you want to call effectively this by default:

```cpp
explicit map( const std::less<Key>& comp, const std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>& alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const Key, T>>() );
```

That is why only `std::less` works by default when you construct instances of `mydef`.

You need to change your declaration of `mydef` in order to use `std::greater` instead:

```cpp
typedef std::map<double, std::queue<something>, std::greater<double>> mydef;
auto t1 = mydef{std::less<double>()}; // error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'mydef' ....
auto t2 = mydef{std::greater<double>()}; // works
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::greater` is a template. `std::greater<T>` is a type. The comparator is a template type argument of `std::map`.

`std::map<double, std::queue<something>>` uses the default comparator type that is `std::less<double>`. That is why you can instantiate the map using an instance of `std:less` but not any other comparator.

You need to specify the comparison object type in the instantiation of `std::map` template: `std::map<double, std::queue<something>, std::greater<>>`.

Comment: Thanks, how should I interpret this constructor definition then?

`explicit map( const Compare& comp, const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );  `

Comment: The point of this is that it allows passing in comparators that have state. I couldn't invent a use case for this, however. ;)

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt it's very convenient when you have an object with many comparable sub-items, the state can tell you which element to compare.